# Ember Js: Error when navigating between dynamic segment of a same route (Failed to excecute 'insertBefore')

Tags: node.js, ember.js, domexception

I get an error when navigating between dynamic segment of the same route
for example when I navigate between **/project/my-project/** to **/project/my-project/gallery** everything works fine.

But when I navigate from `/project/my-project/` to `/project/my-other-project` 
or `/project/my-project/gallery` to `/project/my-other-project`

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The
>   node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of
>   this node
>
> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

This is part of my application route structure
[image]

which is written in router.js like this

```
this.route('project', {path: '/project/:seo_url'}, function() {
 this.route('gallery');
});
```

this is what i wrote in project.hbs

```
<Project::Banner @title="{{this.model.name}}" @image="assets/images/projects/project-banner.jpg"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="tabs has-border-bottom">
            {{#link-to "project.index" this.model.seo_url}}Description{{/link-to}}
            {{#link-to "project.gallery" this.model.seo_url}}Gallery{{/link-to}}
            {{#link-to "project.index" 'my-other-project'}}Error When I click this{{/link-to}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
{{liquid-outlet}}

<Home::ProjectSlider @title="Latest Projects" @projects={{this.model.latest_projects}}/>
```

project/index.hbs

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                placeholder content
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="project-detail-description">
                    <h5>Description {{this.model.seo_url}}</h5>
                    {{{this.model.description}}}
                    <div class="categories">
                        <h5>Scope of Work</h5>
                        {{#each this.model.categories as |category|}}
                            <div class="category">{{category}}</div>
                        {{/each}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

project/gallery.hbs

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row project-gallery index-items">
            {{#each this.model.gallery as |picture|}}
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="project-item">
                        <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{env 'rootURL'}}{{picture}}">
                            <img src="{{env 'rootURL'}}{{picture}}">
                            <div class="gradient-overlay full"></div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

*Project::Banner* and *Home::ProjectSlider* are components and I don't know if they are relevant to this problem.

**UPDATE 1**

I Tried removing

`<Home::ProjectSlider @title="Latest Projects" @projects={{this.model.latest_projects}}/>` from my project.hbs and I didn't get any error.

Here is the code of my home/project-slider.hbs

```
<section data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="2000">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="clearfix pos-rel">
            <h2 class="inline-block">{{@title}}</h2>
            <LinkTo @route="projects" class="see-more-button">
                <div class="pull-right"><div class="hidden-xs inline-block">See More</div> <FaIcon @icon="arrow-right" /></div>
            </LinkTo>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="banner">
        <div id="projects-slider">
            {{#each @projects as |project|}}
            <div class="project-item">
                {{#link-to 'project.index' project.seo_url}}
                    <img src="{{env 'rootURL'}}{{project.image}}" alt="{{project.title}}">
                    <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
                    <div class="project-detail">
                        <h5>{{project.name}}</h5>
                        <div class="btn-flat alt2 inline-block"><span>See the work</span></div>
                    </div>
                {{/link-to}}
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container has-border-bottom"></div>
</section>
```

The **{{#each}}** code is giving me errors and I'm clueless why.

**UPDATE 2**

I think slick slider initialization is what giving me errors
when I comment them, I don't get errors but obviously my slider is not working either.

here is the code of components/home/project-slider.js
I hope somebody would kindly look into it

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
    didInsertElement() {
        // this._super(...arguments);
        $('#projects-slider').slick({
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: false,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1440,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 769,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

    }
});
```

Comment: add code for `project.gallery` controller

Comment: I've added them just now. env is a helper used to get ENV configuration from environment.js

Comment: also the project.gallery does not have a controller

Comment: The problem is probably related to what *slick slider*. Especially that you use it on an ember `{{#each`. Ember relies on DOM references to manipulate the DOM, and if it messes up with them. I would recommend to either use a fully ember based carousel, or do the carousel 100% manually and dont rely on the ember `{{#each`.

Comment: would you mind explaining more on how to not rely on {{#each}}? I provide the list of slider images through an array.